# Import these scanners into another class?

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

Again I am very new to Java, and I have this code here:
package Final;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Position {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner MyPos = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(" Enter Position: ");
    String Pos = MyPos.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Position: "+Pos);

    Scanner MyMains = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Mains: ");
    String Mains1 = MyMains.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Mains: "+Mains1);

    Scanner WScore = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Ward Score: ");
    String score = WScore.nextLine();
    System.out.println(" Average Ward Score is:"+score);
    }
}
```

I was curious if there was a way to possibly import all 3 of my scanners to another class without moving all the actual code from this class? The class I'm trying to move it to is a class called "Player.java". There aren't any problems with my code, but additional input is always appreciate to help me understand and improve my code!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a new scanner for each variable. What you *do* need to do is close() a scanner when you are done using it.

You are thinking of the Scanner itself being associated with a variable - when in fact it is associated with System.in...

So, every time you want another variable, just do:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

String firstThing = sc.nextLine();
String secondThing = sc.nextLine();

sc.close(); // Do this when you're done storing input from System.in!
```

Once you have declared your scanner. I'm not sure why you would want to pass the scanner to another class. What you can do easily is pass the *variables* that you grab from your scanner into a player object.

Just do `Player p1 = new Player(stringYouScanned);` assuming that you have your constructor in your Player class accept a String.

Or, look up **getter and setter methods**. Then you can do something like: `p1.setPosition(4);' (you could replace 4 with an int you scanned in, you get the idea).

If for some reason you want to scan input from within the Player, I'd just initialize a new Scanner, but make sure you are doing `sc.close();` after you are done processing your input.